# Prestashop Back office Module - View / Smarty / Uncaught exception SmartyException

Tags: php, model-view-controller, module, smarty, prestashop-1.5

I am working on the implementation of a Prestashop Back Office module. I added the new Tab in the install file

I have error messages on the display of the view.

Mostly probably something is missing in my implementation.

The module name is : mydashboard

I placed the tpl file in the folder /web/modules/mydashboard/views/templates/admin/mydashboard

Error messages are

/var/www/clients/client2986/web12226/web/modules/mydashboard Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to load template file '/var/www/clients/client2986/web12226/web/admin11/themes/default/template//var/www/clients/client2986/web12226/web/modules/mydashboard/views/templates/admin/mydashboard/dashboard.tpl'' in /var/www/clients/client2986/web12226/web/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php:127 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/clients/client2986/web12226/web/classes/controller/AdminController.php(1152): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch() #1 /var/www/clients/client2986/web12226/web/classes/controller/Controller.php(185): AdminControllerCore->display() #2 /var/www/clients/client2986/web12226/web/classes/Dispatcher.php(348): ControllerCore->run() #3 /var/www/clients/client2986/web12226/web/admin11/index.php(50): DispatcherCore->dispatch() #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/clients/client2986/web12226/web/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 127

```
class AdminMyDashboardController extends ModuleAdminController
{
public $searchflag = 0;
public $datefrom = 0;
public $dateto = 0;
public $orderstatus = 0;
public $datalist = array();

public function __construct()
{       
    // Set variables
    $this->table = 'my_table';
    $this->className = 'MyDashboard';
    $this->actions = array('mysearchorder', 'myresetsearchorder');

    // Set context
    $this->context = Context::getContext();
    $this->context->controller = $this;

    $this->bootstrap = true;

    parent::__construct();

    $this->meta_title = $this->l('My Dashboard');
    $this->toolbar_title[] = $this->meta_title;

}


public function initContent()
{   
    parent::initContent();
    $this->loadObject(true);

    // Order List
    $this->datelist = $this->object->getDataList();     
    $this->context->smarty->assign('datalist', $this->datelist);

    //Search flag
    $this->context->smarty->assign('searchflag', $this->searchflag);


    $this->setTemplate('dashboard.tpl');        
}

public function setMedia()
{
    $sepa = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    $css_directory = $sepa.'modules'.$sepa.MyCommon::getModuleName().$sepa.'views'.$sepa.'css'.$sepa.'mydashboard.css';
    $this->addCSS($css_directory, 'all');

    $js_directory = $sepa.'modules'.$sepa.MyCommon::getModuleName().$sepa.'views'.$sepa.'js'.$sepa.'mydashboard.js';
    $this->addJS($js_directory, 'all');

    return parent::setMedia();
}

/**
* postProcess
*
* @param mixed $token
* @return void
*/


public function postProcess($token = null)
{
    $this->loadObject(true);

    parent::postProcess($token);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here /var/www/clients/client2986/web12226/web/admin11/themes/default/template//var/www/clients/client2986/web12226/web/modules/mydashboard/views/templates/admin/mydashboard/dashboard.tpl

I guess your *MyCommon::getModuleName()* returns not path that you expected for using here.